# O que significa i-esimo em um array?

Tags: array, matriz, matemática

O que significa i-ésimo, estou com dificuldades para entender o seu uso em *arrays* e matrizes.

Comment: O i-ésimo é geralmente usado para indicar algum tipo de elemento genérico de um conjunto de dados, pode ser em um vetor ou uma matriz.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quando você se refere ao índice 0 de um *array*, pode falar o primeiro elemento, certo? Assim como o 1 é o segundo, o 2 é o terceiro, e assim por diante. O 20 é o vigésimo.

Como você falaria sobre o elemento `i` do *array*? i-esimo. Então quando precisa definir uma posição "genérica" (variável) do *array*, pode usar esta expressão para indicar qual é o elemento que dependerá do valor de `i` para saber a posição real.

> -ésimo (da terminação de centésimo ou milésimo) elemento de composição
>
> Exprime a noção de numeral ordinal e .fracionário (ex.: cagagésimo,
> enésimo, infinitésimo).
>
> "-ésimo", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, https://dicionario.priberam.org/-%C3%A9simo [consultado em
> 03-12-2019].

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Como ficaria o uso da palavra para descrever algum elemento de uma matriz que deve ser acessada através de `i` e `j`? Poderia ser i-ésimo elemento e j-ésimo elemento?

Comment: Isso, é até mais comum usar o termo n-esimo.